# S3 SDK PutObject access restrict file size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a React-Native app making use of the JS SDK for S3 and I have an IAM policy that allows a user to perform PutObject on a specific file with its name related to the Cognito ID of the logged-in user. This allows a user to change his/her profile picture without any server code needing to run and me having to have unnecessary data transfer inside AWS.

This works fine expect for the fact that a rouge/modified client can upload a massive file and generate costs for me.

I would like to know if there is a way to restrict the PutObject access to only allow files under a certain size?

Comment: Im almost positive there is no part of the s3 sdk that lets you limit the size of what you upload via putObject. Maybe you could think about leveraging some other check before performing the upload operation

Comment: @Maxwelll technically I do not want to use the SDK to enforce this, I would like to use an IAM policy. I am just mentioning that my access to S3 is through the SDK rather than something else.

Comment: Super hack, an S3 object-created event triggers a Lambda function.  In the event data, Records[0].s3.object.size automatically contains the size of the uploaded object.  If excessive... delete it.  Or try to resize it. Or replace it with grumpy cat.  In all seriousness, you may want to consider some kind of post-processing Lambda trigger for profile pics, anyway... after all, you don't want to expose a user's home or work location in the EXIF metadata of their profile photo...

Comment: @Michael that is what I guessed I would need to do if nothing elegant came up. I can strip EXIF in the app and then only people not using the app to access my service will be compromised (a good thing...)

Comment: Ha!  Sounds like you're on top of it.  Or do the uploads through API Gateway, since it appears there's an intrinsic payload limit there of only 10 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limiting the size of an S3 upload is not possible using IAM or S3 policies.

You will need to write code on your web site (or similar service) to manage the upload and authorization process.